# Links opening on original page with jQuery.bPopup.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bpopup

I hope someone can help me with the following problem. I am currently using jQuery.bPopup.js script for a popup I am using. After a few days I finally managed to get it working, however I am experiencing a small problem. Since my jQuery / PHP knowledge is almost to non-existent I cannot seem get it working properly.

The problem is every link, inside the popup, opens inside the popup, while it should open on the mainpage, or better said; the background page. I tried contacting the author of the script, however he doesn't seem to respond, so I am guessing he is on vacation.

I rather not ditch this popup script, because I already spend a lot of time to get it working properly. Also the script itself is working fine, however for some reason it opens links within the popup instead of opening them on the main page.

Anybody got an idea on how to solve this?

The code I am using is show below.

in the  section:

```
    // Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
    // Encapsulation
    // $ is assigned to jQuery
    ;(function($) {

    // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

    // Binding a click event
    // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
    $('#colorButton').bind('click', function(e) {

    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
    e.preventDefault();

    // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    content:'iframe', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
    contentContainer:'.customcontent',
    loadUrl: 'popup-page.php' //Uses jQuery.load()
    });
    jQuery('iframe').attr("width", 920);
    jQuery('iframe').attr("height", 400);
    jQuery('iframe').attr("scrolling","no", "frameborder","0");
    });
    });
    })(jQuery);
```

And in the  section I am using:

```
<button id="colorButton" style="width:100%;">testbutton</span></button>
<div id="element_to_pop_up"><div class="customcontent"></div><span class="button b-close">X</span></div>
```

Though the popup works fine and it displays the contents also fine, it opens links within the popup, instead of opening them on the main / background page.

I hope I posted all the necessary information. I am kinda clueless (yeah, that happens a lot in general).

Comment: Has anyone some idea on how to solve this? I really don't know on how to solve this... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nobody has a solution? :(

Comment: Another bump and really hoping someone knows how to solve this problem...